What is the slightly slimy stuff on on the white parts of bok-choy and Chinese cabbage?
This in the USA, I buy bok-choy and Chinese cabbage just from a typical "better" supermarket (for what it's worth, not organic or such, just typical "good quality" supermarket produce).
I typically wash in plain cold water bok-choy and similar, fill up the sink and rub-down each frond by hand then soak it for awhile too.
There's definitely a slimy substance on, I believe, mainly the white parts. Even if the veg is seemingly very fresh, or at any rate, straight off the truck.
You can't really "see" this slight slime, its' something you plainly feel; I'll try to take some sort of photo or video though.
After plenty of fresh water it does (seem?) to come off, once dry the slightly slimy feel is gone.
What is this ?
Am I actually foolishly throwing away a nutrient rich coating or something? Is it natural? Some treatment?
I have seen that the store in question does have tiny signs in the produce area "we sometimes wax produce", but I haven't looked into that, and, it is likely irrelevant to this issue, but, who knows.

You sure this thing is fresh? Is it every time you buy it - how many times have you bought from this shop? Does it have a smell? Is the slime visible in the shop? Can you add a photo of the vegetable with the slime?

cheers @Luciano ; 100s of times; no smell; seems incredibly fresh otherwise (excellent supplier, and I only buy veg when they are literally off the truck that morning, I am tight with all the staff); the slime is not really visible, you feel it clearly - will try to photograph

Very strange. Usually slime in raw cabbage is a sign of spoilage, and I have never seen either bok choy or chinese cabbage with slime (from the shop or even during fermentation). If you could ask someone at the shop or the supplier they would probably know.

@Luciano good information, clearly it's not "something everyone knows about but me" (fortunately!)  I happened to get a super-fresh bokchoy this AM and indeed "no slime".  I'm now wondering if it's just how they get when they are say a day old, or .. who knows

You know what, the Publix has those annoying water-mist sprayers over the veg. I wonder if it's that simple?  A few hours under a water mister may do it?  IDK.

We grow our own bok choy and buy it regularly (out of season). I've never noticed anything like this.

a mystery.  i reckon it relates to the misters

Another thought: Whenever I cut apart e.g. a leek, spring onion or onion, they feel a bit 'slimy' too. Most of it is just plant sap, I guess, which goes away when drying a bit (not necessarily when washing). I wonder if you're not just feeling plant sap... ever noticed a similar same feeling with an onion or leek, perhaps?

@Tinkeringbell YES< THAT IS EXACTLY IT - precisely the same in a leek.  So you're saying it is "plant sap" ?  Surely this should be an answer?!

I'll first do some research to see if what I'm calling 'plant sap' is actually that then ;)

@Tinkeringbell magnificent.  I have added the biggest bounty I have the money for!

I think what you're noticing is just 'vegetable/fruit juice', for lack of a better word. It's mostly water + whatever else there can be in vegetable/fruit juice.
As you confirmed in the comments, you also notice this when cutting up leeks or onions. The 'slimy' in my experience is then just a combination of smooth surface + vegetable/fruit juice and/or plain water. It will indeed disappear after drying: It either becomes sticky or disappears entirely. You may not notice it on the 'leafy' parts of vegetables like cabbage and bok choy much, because those aren't as smooth on the outside as the 'white' parts that connect to a stalk/each other. And the 'white part' is also the part where you make a first cut/break to separate leaves, so that would be the point where any 'juice' in the vegetable comes out and can be smeared onto the rest of it.

Huh!  In short that all sounds about right to me. Pretty logical !
